# My iPhone is in Ineligible Devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode7, ios9.1

I'm Using Xcode 7 official release(Not the beta). And iOS 9.1 Beta in my iPhone. And my device is in ineligible devices when I try to run the App in my iPhone. I know that Xcode 7 supports only upto devices iOS 9. Is there any other solution to make this work.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 supports iOS 9.0.  You want Xcode 7.1 beta 2 (at the time of writing) for iOS 9.1 beta support.

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/):

[image]